# Where to put helper arrays in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helper array which is the result of some *expensive* pre-computation needed by page loads. I do not want to store it into the database for a variety of reasons, but would rather prefer it sitting in the memory. Is that advisable? If so, where can I put it (this "cache" array)? Is it a good practice to use a global variable `$array`?

What I have tried:

```
class MyController
  def precompute
    @@array = # pre-computation
  end

  def index
    # use @@array data for page load; pre-computation done earlier elsewhere
  end
end
```

and

```
module MyModule
  def precompute
    @@array = # pre-computation
  end
  def array; @@array end
end

class MyController
  def index
    # use MyModule.array data for page load; pre-computation done earlier elsewhere
  end
end
```

Both of these two do not work, probably due to multi-threading. After pre-computation being done for a while, Rails complains that the class variable is no longer initialized.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Are these helpers any different from regular modules? I  tried putting the helper array into a class variable of a regular module, creating a reader of the variable inside the module, and accessing the variable from outside by `MyModule.class_var_reader`. However it becomes uninitialized after a while too (again, probably due to multi-threading).

Comment: Add the code involved in the problem, maybe this way I and all the other users in SO can understand more accuratelly what's the problem you're facing.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I just improved the description and added some code.